# How do I add a property to all objects in an array based on current property using rxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

For example I get back an array of objects with several properties - I want to add a new property `_dead : true` if `deathDate` is populated on the current object. How do I do this? I am new to RxJs and ES6.

```
    return this.myAPI.get(`/players`).pipe(
      map(player => ({
          ...player,
          _dead: player.deathDate,
        }),
      )
    );
```

Comment: should be quite simple if I understand your question correctly :)
Just add ternary condition onto you _dead property: `_dead: player.deathDate ? true : false`

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be confusing RxJS's map operator, with the `Array.map()` method.

According to the RxJS [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map), the purpose of the `map()` operator is to

> Apply projection with each value from source.

If you wish to add a new property to the array of objects, you will need to use the [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate through the array.

This is how we can modify your code to achieve the desired results.

```
return this.myAPI.get(`/players`).pipe(
  map(players => ({
      const res = players.map(player => ({
        ...player,
        _dead: !!player.deathDate,
      });

      return res;
    }),
  )
);
```